Modifying music variable duration in LilyPond music function
The LilyPond documentation has an example where they describe how to use a function to make a customizable measure of music.
simpleAccompaniment =
#(define-music-function
   (bass-1 bass-2 chord) (ly:music? ly:music? ly:music?)
   #{
     #bass-1 #chord #bass-2 #chord
   #})

{
  \clef bass
  \simpleAccompaniment c g, <e g>
  \simpleAccompaniment d g, <f g>
}

This turns the 3 input parameters into 4 outputs.

Now say I want to make it so it's not straight quarter notes.
I tried $bass-18 to make it an eighth note instead, but it complains Unbound variable: bass-18
I tried ${bass-1}8, but it complains Unbound variable: #{\x7b;bass-1\x7d;8}#
I tried {$bass-1}8, but it complains Unbound variable: #{bass-1\x7d;8}#
I tried $bass-1 8, but that puts a quarter note, then a copy of it as an eighth note.
I tried turning it into a chord which works when the input was a single note like with < $bass-1 >8, but breaks when the input is already a chord like with < $chord >8 with error
error: not a rhythmic event
     < 
       $chord >8

I can modify the duration on the calling side \simpleAccompaniment c4. g,8 <e g>4, but then all my $chords have to be the same duration.
So, how do I modify the duration of the music variables? Is there some escape character sequence that will let me put something other than a space directly following a variable? Is there a way I can suppress the first quarter note so only the eighth note copy shows up?

The reason why this does not work is that the scheme parser will parse bass-18 as one token. It does not know that the 8 is not supposed to be there. What you can do is to instead notate $bass-1 8 (not the need for $ instead of #, so that the expression will be parsed with the values in place).
This will of course still not work, as in your case bass-1 is already a note music event, not a pitch (so this would result in something like c4 8, but we want c 8). You could change the type of bass-1 to ly:pitch?, then the above would do the trick.
But this does not work for chords, and also you might want to be able to pass in articulations and stuff. So instead you can take the input as music and adjust the duration:
simpleAccompaniment =
#(define-music-function
   (bass-1 bass-2 chord) (ly:music? ly:music? ly:music?)
   (define (with-duration-internal m duration)
     (cond ((or (music-is-of-type? m 'note-event) (music-is-of-type? m 'rest-event) (music-is-of-type? m 'skip-event))
            (ly:music-set-property! m 'duration (apply ly:make-duration duration)))
           ((music-is-of-type? m 'event-chord)
            (map (lambda (n) (with-duration-internal n duration))
                 (ly:music-property m 'elements)))
           (else (ly:warning "Neither note event nor chord")))
     m)
   (define (with-duration m . duration)
     ; Work on copy instead of mutating original for safety
     (set! m (ly:music-deep-copy m))
     (with-duration-internal m duration))
   #{
     #(with-duration bass-1 3 1) #(with-duration chord 4) #(with-duration bass-2 3) #(with-duration chord 3)
   #})

{
  \clef bass
  \simpleAccompaniment c g, <e g>
  \simpleAccompaniment d g, <f g>
  \simpleAccompaniment r s <f g>
}


Thanks! I moved the with-duration functions outside of simpleAccompaniment by adding a # in front so they could be used in other functions. The new logarithmic plus dot duration format is weird, but I think I got the hang of it.

I'm having trouble getting it to work with the example a couple pages later which adds in a make-relative command that makes it work with relative clefs. It complains syntax error, unexpected EVENT_IDENTIFIER and Unbound variable: #{\x7d;}# and Unbound variable: bass-1.

OK. I got it working with make-relative. I don't know what I was doing wrong. Probably some mismatched parenthesis or something.

@Stephen If you don’t like using ly:make-duration you could also pass in the duration using #{ 8. #}.
